# Problemas al registrar datos en MySQL con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style2.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
<?php
session_start();

/*-----------------REGISTRO--------------------*/
include("conexion.php");


$nom=trim($_POST['nombre']);
$ape=trim($_POST['apellido']);
$cor=trim($_POST['correo']);
$con=trim($_POST['contra']);
$con_encr= password_hash($con, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$dir=trim($_POST['direccion']);
$tel=trim($_POST['telefono']);
$emp=trim($_POST['empresa']);
$fec_reg=date("d/m/y");

$cont_nombre = strlen($_POST['nombre']);
$cont_apellido = strlen($_POST['apellido']);
$cont_correo = strlen($_POST['correo']);
$cont_contra = strlen($_POST['contra']);
$cont_contra2 = strlen($_POST['contra2']);
$cont_direccion = strlen($_POST['direccion']);
$cont_telefono = strlen($_POST['telefono']);
$cont_empresa = strlen($_POST['empresa']);

if ($cont_nombre <= 1 && $cont_apellido <= 1 && $cont_correo <=1 && $cont_contra <= 1 &&
    $cont_contra2 <= 1 && $cont_direccion <=1 && $cont_telefono <=1 && $cont_empresa <=1) {

            $query= "insert into usuarios(nombre, apellido, correo, contraseña, direccion, telefono, empresa, fecha_registro) values ('$nom', '$ape', '$cor', '$con_encr', '$dir', '$tel', '$emp', '$fec_reg')";
            $resultado= mysqli_query($conex,$query);

     }else{
        ?>
        <h1 class="bad">COMPLETE CORRECTAMENTE TODOS LOS CAMPOS</h3>
        <?php
          }                                                                 
?>
```

Entiendo que es un código inseguro, pero es solo para irme familiarizando con PHP y MySQL, bueno, explico un poco como funciona, tengo un archivo **registro.php** que básicamente es el formulario, el cuál redirige a éste código los datos y de aquí se procesan para darse de alta en la base de datos.

Mi **conexion.php**, el cúal es el encargado de conectarse al servidor me marca como que la conexión esta hecha correctamente, sin embargo al momento de dar en Registrar me ejecuta directamente el  de esta parte, dando así una incógnita para mi sobre cuál es el error, alguien me comentaba que era posible que el proveedor hubiese bloqueado los registros por motivos de seguridad, ya que el día de ayer si me permitía dar de alta, ahí tengo 2 registros, pero el día de hoy al agregar mas condiciones al código me encuentro con que no funciona, pensé: 'no pasa nada simplemente borro lo que agregué y listo', pero no fue así, al quitar la parte que hizo que dejara de funcionar continuó igual, lo que me hace pensar que borré de más, o quizá altere algo antes, no lo sé.

Incluso borré otras cosas que me estaban dando error, las cuáles estoy consciente de que modifiqué, como por ejemplo unos **header** en la parte donde está el **h1**, borré la parte que validaba si **$resultado** se había concretado, o sea dado de alta los datos, pero continuó igual.

**El if es para validar que los datos son mayores a 1 caracter, los datos los esta recibiendo exitosamente del formulario de registro.php, ya lo verifiqué**

Una imagen de lo que me muestra al intentar registrar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: verifica como es el formato del campo fecha_registro en la tabla, ya que esta debe ser igual al usado en la tabla que por defecto es YYY-MM-DD, esa es una de las cosas por las cuales no te puede insertar registro

Comment: @AlexanderRodriguez en la tabla declare la fecha como VARCHAR, no como fecha

Comment: Ok voy a probar el codigo para darte una respuesta de lo que esta pasando

Comment: Muchas gracias, quedo al pendiente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**La solucion al codigo es la siguiente:**

** 1) El campo contraseña estaba siendo pasado en otro formato sin utf8** por lo que la tilde no era conocida y se consideraba otro campo. (recomiendo usar campos tipo **ANSI X3.4-1986** sin acentos, tildes, es universal y funciona al 100%)

**2) La validacion estaba fallando en su condicion** le estabas diciendo a que si $cont_nombre es menor o igual a <= 1 para cada uno de los campos.

Basandome en la informacion suministrada

Hice una tabla con todos los campo tipo varchar 128 y sin campos nulos por lo que es obligatorio colocar todos los campos para poder agregar un registro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo con las correcciones es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style2.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
<?php

/*-----------------REGISTRO--------------------*/
include("conexion.php");

// entrada de datos desde el formulario
$nom=trim($_POST['nombre']);
$ape=trim($_POST['apellido']);
$cor=trim($_POST['correo']);
$con=trim($_POST['contra']);
$con_encr= password_hash($con, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$dir=trim($_POST['direccion']);
$tel=trim($_POST['telefono']);
$emp=trim($_POST['empresa']);
$fec_reg=date("d/m/y");
// validacion de campos vacios
$cont_nombre = strlen($_POST['nombre']);
$cont_apellido = strlen($_POST['apellido']);
$cont_correo = strlen($_POST['correo']);
$cont_contra = strlen($_POST['contra']);
$cont_contra2 = strlen($_POST['contra2']);
$cont_direccion = strlen($_POST['direccion']);
$cont_telefono = strlen($_POST['telefono']);
$cont_empresa = strlen($_POST['empresa']);

// si hay un campo vacio no se ejecuta
if ($cont_nombre >= 1 && $cont_apellido >= 1 && $cont_correo >=1 && $cont_contra >= 1 &&
    $cont_contra2 >= 1 && $cont_direccion >=1 && $cont_telefono >=1 && $cont_empresa >=1) {

            // Usar utf8_decode() para poder pasar nombre campo contraseña (ñ)
            $sql = utf8_decode("INSERT INTO usuarios 
            (nombre, apellido, correo, contraseña, direccion, telefono, empresa, fecha_registro) 
            VALUES ('$nom', '$ape', '$cor', '$con_encr', '$dir', '$tel', '$emp', '$fec_reg')");

            // Ejecucion de la consulta y verificacion
            if(mysqli_query($conex, $sql)){
            echo "<br>Han sido insertado los registro de forma exitosa";
            } else{
            echo "<br>ERROR: no se pudo ejecutar la sentencia:  $sql. " . mysqli_error($conex);
            }

            //  Cerrar conexion
            mysqli_close($conex);

    } else {
        ?>
           <h1 class="bad">COMPLETE CORRECTAMENTE TODOS LOS CAMPOS</h3>
        <?php
    }

?>
```

Use en el codigo el comando `utf8_decode()` para que pueda pasar la tilde del nombre del campo contraseña.

```
$sql = utf8_decode("INSERT INTO usuarios 
            (nombre, apellido, correo, contraseña, direccion, telefono, empresa, fecha_registro) 
            VALUES ('$nom', '$ape', '$cor', '$con_encr', '$dir', '$tel', '$emp', '$fec_reg')");
```

**Para probar el codigo sin crear un formulario hice lo siguiente:**

Documente el area de entrada de los datos en $_POST[] y tambien el grupo de validacion por strlen() para colocar este bloque y probar el funcionamiento, cosa que fue favorable ya que hizo verificar los fallos y corregir el codigo para su funcionamiento.

```
$nom='alex';
$ape='rodriguez';
$cor='al@gmail.com';
$con='1234';
$con_encr= password_hash($con, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$dir='mi cas';
$tel='900-0000';
$emp='mi empresa personal';
$fec_reg=date("d/m/y");

$cont_nombre = strlen($nom);
$cont_apellido = strlen($ape);
$cont_correo = strlen($cor);
$cont_contra = strlen($con);
$cont_contra2 = strlen($con);
$cont_direccion = strlen($dir);
$cont_telefono = strlen($tel);
$cont_empresa = strlen($emp);
```

Conserve la logica y estructura que estas trabajando para que sea mas facil entender el codigo y seguir avanzandolo pero puedes mejorar muchas cosas si:

A) Usa el campo de tipo fecha por el costo que implica almacenar un string ante un date, tambien se te complica mucho a la hora de hacer calculo y conversiones de fecha, cambios de formato en fecha y otras cosas.

B) Pasas todo el sistema de validaciones a formulario y lo evaluas con Jquery o alguna libreria JS, tambien con atributos en los campos input y dejas que el codigo post.php se encargue solo de almacenamiento lo cual te ayudara a su mantenimiento y reutilizacion en otras partes del sistema.

UN APORTE ADICIONAL A TU CODIGO PODRIA SE LO SIGUIENTE:

puedes optimizar la validacion del post usando un for each que recorra el arreglo del $_POST[] y este al pasar por cada item le evaluas el la cantidad de caracteres que tiene el campo, si no tiene un valor entonces pones una variable marcador llamada $vacio=true y esta sera entonces tu variable a evaluar en la condicion de entrada if() que usas para registrar los datos, es decir, si la variable vacio es **verdad** entonces pones un inversor `if (!$vacio)` que te dara como resultado falso y no ejecuta el bloque, en cambio si es falso quiere decir que todos los campos tiene un contenido y no fue cambiada la variable `$vacio` y se ejecuta el contenido del if()

Aqui te adjunto el codigo de validacion mejorado:

cambia este codigo:

```
// validacion de campos vacios
    $cont_nombre = strlen($_POST['nombre']);
    $cont_apellido = strlen($_POST['apellido']);
    $cont_correo = strlen($_POST['correo']);
    $cont_contra = strlen($_POST['contra']);
    $cont_contra2 = strlen($_POST['contra2']);
    $cont_direccion = strlen($_POST['direccion']);
    $cont_telefono = strlen($_POST['telefono']);
    $cont_empresa = strlen($_POST['empresa']);
```

Por este otro:

```
// validar campo vacio
$vacio = false;
foreach($_POST as $key => $valor){
    $largo = strlen($valor);
    if ($largo<1) { $vacio = true; }
 }
```

y cambia el codigo del if()

```
 // si hay un campo vacio no se ejecuta
    if ($cont_nombre >= 1 && $cont_apellido >= 1 && $cont_correo >=1 && $cont_contra >= 1 &&
        $cont_contra2 >= 1 && $cont_direccion >=1 && $cont_telefono >=1 && $cont_empresa >=1) {
```

por este otro if()

```
// si hay un campo vacio no se ejecuta
if (!$vacio) {
```